# How Can I Avoid This For Loop? (R)

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I currently have a for loop as below and it does not run as fast as I would like it to.

```
library(dplyr)

DF<-data.frame(Name=c('Bob','Joe','Sally')) #etc

PrimaryResult <- Function1(DF)
ResultsDF<-Function2(PrimaryResult)

for(i in 1:9) 
{
  Filtered<-filter(DF,Name!=PrimaryResult[i,2])
  NextResult <- Function1(Filtered)
  ResultsDF<-rbind(ResultsDF,Function2(NextResult))
   }
```

The code takes an initial result of Function1 (which is a list of names) and tries it again with each name in the initial result being excluded individually to provide alternative results. These are returned as a one row data frame via Function2 and appended to the Results data frame.

How can I make this faster?

Comment: The for loop is almost certainly not the slow part - probably it's your Function2 that is slow. You should first [profile your code](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html) to find what is actually slow and improve that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your main problem is the appending results from function 2 each iteration with `rbind`. This is classically slow because you are telling `R` to rewrite a bunch of information at each time step and `R` does not really know how large of a vector you are going to end up with.

Try making your results into a list vector.  I don't really know what your functions do so I can't really assist with that part.

```
results_list <- vector("list", 10)
results_list[[1]] <- Function2(PrimaryResult)

for(i in 1:9){
  Filtered<-filter(DF,Name!=PrimaryResult[i,2])
  NextResult <- Function1(Filtered)
  results_list[[i+1]]<-rbind(results_list[[i]],Function2(NextResult))
   }
```

This is not perfect, but it should speed things up a bit.

Comment: OP's example is `for(i in 1:9)`. While growing a data frame with rbind is poor practice, 9 calls to rbind will not make a noticeable performance difference. And even then, this solution doesn't *still* rbinds at every step, so the only difference is that you are saving each incremental result. To eliminate the `rbind` you should delete it from inside the loop and after the loop finish with `results = `do.call(rbind, results_list)` or `results = dplyr::bind_rows(results_list)`.